# How to dump database to a remote server?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to push my database to a remote mysql database hosted on ClearDB.

I'm using the command

```
 mysql -u username@us-cdbr-east-*** -pmypwd dbname < mydb.sql
```

I'm getting the error

```
 Access denied for user 'bbea98e4ba67c1@us-cdbr-east-**@localhost (using password YES)
```

Am i using the correct syntax ? I tried importing the same sql file to a local database and it happened smoothly.

DO i need to GRANT some proviledges to this remote database on heroku ? If yes then how should i do it ?

Comment: Note that Heroku does not host MySQL databases.

Comment: It does support cleardb database which is in fact MySQL. I pushed database successfully thanks to the answer given below.

Comment: Note that Heroku does not **host** MySQL databases. ClearDB is an add-on provider; it is not operated by Heroku. Heroku acts as a middle man here.

Comment: Thanks @ctshyrock. You are right. I meant the big picture. One can integrate the database with the app with the help of addon.

Comment: I'm sure you were aware, I was only commenting for anyone who comes across this in the future :)

Comment: That's so considerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have privileges set on the database to be accessed from the remote host where you are trying to read in the dump. When creating access for a username you always specify a corresponding host. This could be % for any host... In that case you don't have to do anything. Sometimes it is set to a specific host, in which case you need to add a privilege for the same username but with a different host being the remote host.

Also you need the correct syntax would be:

```
 mysql -u username -h us-cdbr-east-*** -pmypwd dbname < mydb.sql
```

notice the -h switch